# Unable to load cocoapods - Could not find 'encrypted_strings' - Gem::LoadError

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

I am not able to load cocoapods. No matter what gem command I type in, I get the following error:

```
/Users/jeff//.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': 
Could not find 'encrypted_strings' (>= 0) among 18 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 
'GEM_PATH=/Users/jeff/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:58:in `gem'
from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `<module:Kernel>'
from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:1235:in `require'
from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:1235:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I get this error when I type any of the following:

sudo gem install cocoapods

gem uninstall cocoapods

gem env

sudo gem install encrypted_strings

My mac is running version 10.12.6 osx

I do have Ruby in my /Library. The subdirectories contains Gems/2.0.0.

Note that some time ago, I was working on another project that had me update Ruby to version ruby-2.1.5 and ruby-2.1.5-dev. These are found in "/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies". Now if I go to "/Library/Ruby/Gems", there is a subdirectory called 2.0.0. Is there an incompatibility here?

How can I correct this problem? Should I somehow remove these versions. If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably version of `cocoapods` is running in unsupported version ruby and install again . To fix it remove **all** versions of cocoapods. How to do it find at answer https://superuser.com/a/686319

It can be happen after updating to new macOS version.
To prevent it happen in future use [rbenv Ruby environment](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

`rbenv` allows to not use **root** access

Comment: Actually, even trying to remove all versions of cocoapods in the provided link fails. The first suggestion in the link was to determine which version of cocoapods is installed with the following command: "gem list --local | grep cocoapods". This results in the same error message recorded in the problem statement. Some time ago, I was working on another project that had me update Ruby to version ruby-2.1.5 and ruby-2.1.5-dev. These are found in "/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies". Now if I go to "/Library/Ruby/Gems", there is a subdirectory called 2.0.0. Is there an incompatibility here?

Comment: hm, to check which ruby version is active in your system execute
`$ ruby --version`

Mine is ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-darwin16.5.0]
Then you need to install required

Comment: Mine is ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]. Can you think of any way to get around this problem where every gem command results in the same error? Should I delete something using unix commands? I am really at a loss on how to fix this. Do  I need to remove one of the versions? If so, how?

Comment: You don't need to delete anything. Install ruby environment as described at https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv . Then install ruby version 2.0.0p648. Then `cocoapods` have to work. I prefer to install `rbenv` using "Basic GitHub checkout" way https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout